# How can i get the previous directory list after opening a file from directory/file list?

Tags: vim, editor

```
vim .
```

Now selecting a file I opened it, now how can I get back the previous window with that `vim .`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you try to edit a directory (like `vim .`) you get the directory explorer. Edit inside vim:

```
:e .
```

Thanks to jumplists, one can back up to the directory browser with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in normal mode. That will work best if you don't jump between files in the between.

Comment: :e . will edit the current directory. Suppose i started like vim /var/www/site. Then opened a file, now i want to get back to that list of /var/www/site, is there anything like Back button or so ?

Comment: @guru, it seems there's __is__ a back button: `C-o` in normal mode will take me back to the listing. May or may not work with you. Also consult `NerdTree` for an enhanced version of the directory listing.

Comment: C-o works perfectly, how can i get the help manual for C-o ? :h ??

Comment: @guru: `:h ctrl-o` will do. It'll talk about jumplists but the directory browser plugin apparently marks the spot jumpable, when you open a new file by return.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to pressing CTRL-o ?

Comment: @guru, I don't think so. You can always map the key to whatever you want.

Comment: Hi @VincentRobert. I understand that some people think the `kbd` stuff is prettier but there is a long history behind the terse and unambiguous `C-o` syntax of describing key bindings. People who use vim or emacs will eventually have to learn the syntax anyway.

Comment: I do not agree that it is unambiguous since I changed it for the specific reason that I did not understand the notation at first. Your argument about learning the syntax is valid but only if an actual explanation had been provided with this specific notation.

Answer (score 3):

`C-o` will go back to the listing but the cursor will be at the end of the listing

C-^ will go back to the listing too, but the cursor will be at the beginning of the listing (e.g. the `..` line)

Does anyone know that how to go back the the previous line of the listing, I mean, if I open a file at the 5th line in the listing, when finishing viewing/editing that file, how to go back the position of 5th line in the listing?